# I cant display backround image in vuejs and tailwindcss

Tags: vue.js, tailwind-css

[components code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T999l.png)

the image dont display in background. and the same thing when i try with "bg-shoes" in tailwindcss

Comment: For future reference, avoid using links to display code samples. They could break at anytime and future users will not be able to benefit from the question. Instead use the code sample tool or the code snippet tool.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that you bind the style property. And that a single curly brace is used in the syntax
`<div v-bind:style="{ backgroundImage: makesure the value is a string }"></div>`

Comment: the same probleme nothing show

Comment: No man, you can't use curly braces for inside open tag, we use dynamique prop like this :src ="url".  and the curly braces we use it like this<tag> {{ }} </tag>

Comment: hhhh thanks for your time. I don't know about react. but I am using vue and I think the framework have some probleme with this kind of structur

Comment: My apologies I was looking at the wrong question. For vue, make the value of the url is a string and that you are CamelCasing